# Array contains a certain structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

When doing complex things with arrays I get confused pretty quickly.

I'm trying to make a function `arrayStructure($candidate, $structure)` which:

- Checks if a `candidate` array **contains** the given `structure`.

What do I have:

```
// The array that will be validated
$candidate = [
    'persons' => [
        'john',
        'amanda'
    ],
    'animals' => [
        'dog',
        'monkey'
    ],
    'aliens' => 'scary_one'
];

// The structure the candidate has to contain
$structure = ['persons', 'animals' => ['species'] ];

arrayStructure($candidate, $structure);
```

This should return **false**, because `$candidate['animals']` doesn't have a key `species`.

Now if we would add an array of species to `$candidate['animals']`, like so:

```
$candidate = [
    'persons' => [
        'john',
        'amanda'
    ],
    'animals' => [
        'species' => [],
        'dog',
        'monkey'
    ],
    'aliens' => 'scary_one'
];

// The structure the candidate has to contain
$structure = ['persons', 'animals' => ['species'] ];

arrayStructure($candidate, $structure);
```

This would return **true**, because $candidate **contains** the structure given in `$structure`.

Note the following:

- The structure and candidate should be checked recursively
- The structure has keys and values: `persons` is not a key but a **value**, but it looks for the `persons` **key** in the candidate. The same goes for `species`.
- The candidate and structure are both multidimensional.
- The function `arrayStructure` check if the candidate contains the keys, thats why it will return true in the second example even though the candidate contains 'aliens' and the structure does not.

Does anyone have an idea how I could accomplish this?

---

Laravel does something similar with JSON structures in their PHPUnit helper function `assertJsonStructure`:

```
public function assertJsonStructure(array $structure = null, $responseData = null)
{
    if (is_null($structure)) {
        return $this->assertJson();
    }

    if (is_null($responseData)) {
        $responseData = $this->decodeResponseJson();
    }

    foreach ($structure as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && $key === '*') {
            PHPUnit::assertInternalType('array', $responseData);

            foreach ($responseData as $responseDataItem) {
                $this->assertJsonStructure($structure['*'], $responseDataItem);
            }
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey($key, $responseData);

            $this->assertJsonStructure($structure[$key], $responseData[$key]);
        } else {
            PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey($value, $responseData);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Making it simpler for arrays (**THIS WORKS WHEN I RUN THE PHPUNIT TEST WITH MY EXAMPLE ABOVE**):

```
public function assertArrayStructure(array $structure = null, array $array)
{
    foreach ($structure as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey($key, $array);

            $this->assertArrayStructure($structure[$key], $array[$key]);
        } else {
            PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey($value, $array);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This is also what I had in my own  experiments, except I couldn't get the array has key to work (PHPUnit does quite some extra thing which I'm trying to figure out).

Comment: Well, pseudo code would be something like `for each value in $structure, check if a key with that name exists in $candidate. if $structure's value is itself an array, also check if its values exists as keys in $candidate[value]` (where, if I'm not mistaken, last last bit could be done with recursion)

Comment: Also, please note that while your question is well written and easy to understand, you are usually supposed to provide your code (attempt) and then ask a specific question in regards to that code. As is, the question *could* be flagged as too broad.

Comment: @domdom I came up with that pseudo code too, but I have no idea how I would write it out. That's why I haven't supplied any code yet. Still trying to figure something out

Comment: Well, you seem to have the right idea and approach, so just go ahead and write some stuff up. It can help to first flesh out the function's signatures and pre- and post-conditions, then actually implement them. Once you run into actual trouble, come back, add your code to the question and get help on the specifics. :)

Comment: Oh, one more thing: make sure to check out [PHP's built-in array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) - maybe something there comes in handy.

Comment: So what is the exact problem here?

Comment: @domdom Gave you some example code of how to do it in PHPunit

Comment: @domdom I solved it! Anything you would change?

Comment: Looks clean and lean to me. Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function arrayStructure(array $structure = null, array $array, &$errors = [])
{
    foreach ($structure as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $array)) $errors[] = false;
            arrayStructure($structure[$key], $array[$key], $errors);
        } else {
            if (!array_key_exists($value, $array)) $errors[] = false;
        }
    }

    return empty($errors);
}
```

We keep adding to a `$errors` array if a key did not exist, meaning that if the errors is not empty the candidate didnt have the structure. This one succeeds:

```
persons is checked in: {"persons":["john","amanda"],"animals":{"species":[],"0":"dog","1":"monkey"},"other":"value"}
animals is checked in: {"persons":["john","amanda"],"animals":{"species":[],"0":"dog","1":"monkey"},"other":"value"}
species is checked in: {"species":[],"0":"dog","1":"monkey"}
bool(true)
```

Now if we remove species, it will fail:

```
persons is checked in: {"persons":["john","amanda"],"animals":["dog","monkey"],"other":"value"}
animals is checked in: {"persons":["john","amanda"],"animals":["dog","monkey"],"other":"value"}
species is checked in: ["dog","monkey"]
bool(false)
```